# Legend load event in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working on arcgis map JavaScript API and i want to show map layer legend with close icon but i am unable to find legend load event to show the same. Legend along with close icon is shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a container div first. add the close button on it.
Then create a child div inside it and attach the legend to the child div.

```
<div id="containerDiv">
    <button type="button">X</button>
    <div id="legendDiv"><div>
</div>

var legend = new Legend({  
                map: map,  
                layerInfos: [{  
                    layer: layer1,  
                    title: "Layer1 Legend"  
                }]  
            }, "legendDiv");
```